# Sharing properties and methods across classes in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an interface class as such.

```
internal interface Venue
{
    int VenueID { get; set; }
    String VenueName { get; set; }
    String VenueAddress1 { get; set; }
    String VenueAddress2 { get; set; }
    String City { get; set; }
    String County { get; set; }
    String Eircode { get; set; }
    int Capacity { get; set; }
    String PhoneNo { get; set; }
    int Fee { get; set; }
    String Status { get; set; }
}
```

I then have two forms that implement this interface, each with its own methods to get data from form controls.

Both forms then are made children a TabPage, 1 form is an Update form, the other is an Add form.

Currently, I can only access the properties via each form type, e.g

```
frmAddVenue addVenue = new frmAddVenue();
frmUpdateVenue updateVenue = new frmUpdateVenue();

// Accessing form properties
addVenue.ID
updateVenue.ID
```

But I would actually like to do something more like this

```
// 
Form venueDetails = new frmAddVenue(); // or new frmUpdateVenue();
venueDetails.ID;
```

Doing something like this would allow me to access each child forms properties which are the exact same and contain the exact same information.

I was going to create a class in each form that inherited from a VenueModel class, but when I went to create overriding methods inside it told me I can't access the forms controls, I also presume this is something to do with form controls not being static.

What would I have to do to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming ID is actually VenueID in your interface and that the forms implement that interface

```
frmAddVenue addVenue = new frmAddVenue();
var id = ((Venue)frmAddVenue).VenueID;
```

ie cast the form to the interace you want to use

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to understand your answer. I am looking for a way to associate both forms as the same type so I can change between them and use the same methods inside them.

Comment: that what I showed

Comment: Yeah I have tried to implement that, I either get "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field" or "An object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property "

Comment: i would need to see the code in detal, please post a new question with more code

Comment: I actually got it working, brilliant answer. Thanks